# Want to display default html if no value is present

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to display default html if there is no value present but it's not working with a price field on a wordpress theme

```
<?php 
$price = the_field('ct_listing_price');
if (!empty($price)) {
?>
<h4 class="price marT0 marB0" style="color:#fff;"><?php ct_listing_price(); ?></h4>
<?php
} else { echo "Price Undisclosed";}
?>
```

I've also tried get_field, but this won't work either. It just starts to display "Price Undisclosed" on every listing despite some having prices.

Comment: can it be that $price is not really empty?

Comment: check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: try echo "-".$price."-"; anything between the dashes?

Comment: Tom, nothing between the dashed when i tried that

Comment: What does `echo strlen($price);` produce?

Comment: David, it produces 0

Comment: Is $price returning null or empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Is this field inside a form?

If so the field should have the input tag with a name `<input name="price">` and the form should have a method either `method = GET` or `method = POST`.
Post is most probable in this case, if thats true than your method for checking if the variable is set would look like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {
//action here
}`
```

Comment: The field is not within a form